# Misalignment of popover for dynamically created button

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a popover along with the button when it is dynamically rendered (on the click of "Add Button").

I am able to display the popover with the required HTML, but how should I align the tip of the popover alongside the button?

Here is the 'plunker' describing the scenario: https://plnkr.co/edit/GApD3WJhsa7afYAXuLJl?p=preview

```
<div class="my-button">
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-bind="instance.name"></button>
  <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. See updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bs0K3FqnIWNjbiMkMygV?p=preview. Inside the link function, compile the popover content and append it inside a hidden <div>.

```
var compiled = $('<div>', {css: {display: 'none'}})
   .append($compile(popoverContent)(scope)).appendTo('body');

button.popover({
  //... other config
  content: compiled.html()
});
```

Once the  is removed (by clicking on the cross icon on the right), the hidden <div> can be removed and popover can be destroyed.